# Store arraylist in the database and retrieve it for offline purpose to recyclerview

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, arraylist

Okay folks!! May be this question is asked a hell lot of times but still i am asking in new way I believe.

I am downloading data from a website using JSOUP parsing and stored it in a arraylist (also loaded in recyclerview). It works perfectly when I am online.
For offline I have done this so far:

--> converted the arraylist into json using gson. 
--> stored the converted in sqlite database (in the json format).

I have multiple columns in a table where multiple json string array is stored. Now I want to do following things:

 --> Retrieve the contents from database (from multiple columns) and again convert it into arraylist so that I can load it into Recyclerview.

--> I want to load these contents in recyclerview on app start and on some other actions.

What could be the best way to do that, if any one can explain me.
Thanks in advanced.

My codes so far:

NewsDatabaseAdapter.java

```
public class NewsDatabaseAdapter {
NewsDatabase dbhelper;
int pos;

public NewsDatabaseAdapter(Context context, int posi) {
    dbhelper = new NewsDatabase(context);


    this.pos = posi;
}

public long insertData(String titles, String dates) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + dbhelper.TABLE_NEWS);
    db.execSQL("VACUUM");
    if (pos == 1) {
        values.put(dbhelper.TITLES, titles);
        values.put(dbhelper.DATE, dates);
    } else if (pos == 2) {
        values.put(dbhelper.MYAGDI_TITLES, titles);
        values.put(dbhelper.MYAGDI_DATE, dates);
    }
    long id = db.insert(dbhelper.TABLE_NEWS, null, values);
    return id;
}


public String getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] column = new String[0];
    if (pos == 1) {
        column = new String[]{dbhelper.ID, dbhelper.TITLES, dbhelper.DATE};
    } else if (pos == 2) {
        column = new String[]{dbhelper.ID, dbhelper.MYAGDI_TITLES, dbhelper.MYAGDI_DATE};
    }
    Cursor cursor = db.query(dbhelper.TABLE_NEWS, column, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int cid = cursor.getInt(0);
        String title = cursor.getString(1);
        String date = cursor.getString(2);
        buffer.append(cid + " " + title + " " + date + "\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}


static class NewsDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbOffline";
    private static final String TABLE_NEWS = "newsTable";
    private static final String ID = "id";

    private static final String TITLES = "newsTitles";
    private static final String DATE = "newsDates";
    private static final String MYAGDI_TITLES = "myagdiTitles";
    private static final String MYAGDI_DATE = "myagdiDates";

    public NewsDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NEWS + "("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + TITLES + " TEXT," + DATE + " TEXT,"
                + MYAGDI_TITLES + " TEXT," + MYAGDI_DATE + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NEWS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addNews(String titles) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(TITLES, titles);

    }
}
}
```

..........................To insert and extract contents from Database...............................

```
            String titles = gson.toJson(mTitles);
            String dates = gson.toJson(mDates);

            dbHelper = new NewsDatabaseAdapter(mContext, posi);


            long id = dbHelper.insertData(titles, dates);
            if (id < 0) {
                Log.d("DATABASE", "No Success");
            } else {
                Log.d("DATABASE", "Success");
            }
            String data = dbHelper.getData();

            Log.d("DATAadsaf", data);
```

Comment: What are you asking for: saving data in SQLite or the better way of what u r doing?

Comment: @chandil03 yes!! how can i save arraylist in SQLite in better way so that I can retrieve it easily again in a arraylist ? May be it also include the better way of what I am doing ??

Comment: Can you please go through my codes ? :) :)

Comment: How big is your JSON file?

Comment: It depends on user actually, he is allowed to scroll through the contents (where data are extracted through asynctask and stored in the same arraylist). It may be 200+. @chandil03 Thank you!!

Comment: Then i will recommend u to save JSON content in a file instead of SQLite.

Comment: Okay, I can do that!! But how do I retrieve then ? Saving two array lists as json array in a file and while retrieving, again retrieve as two arraylists ?

Comment: In which format server is returning data?

Comment: Actually, I am parsing html to get data from a news portal website so the format is in text i guess.

Comment: One more thing sir, I have numbers of headings (like national news, international news,etc) whose data is to saved for offline purpose so i was preferring sqlite to store all of them in different columns. Am I right ?
This is the website.
http://www.myagdikali.com

Comment: In that case SQLite is the feasible. But I couldn't find the column to save JSON in yout database table. I can't recommend you the best way to store data until you show me the data that you want to store.

Comment: U can visit http://myagdikali.com/category/news/national-news . The data I need to store is the news heading and the date of publication. I can have all these data in a arraylist though.

Comment: What does MYAGDI mean in your table?

Comment: It's a district in Nepal. I am extracting news of Myagdi which is in the website.

Comment: Why would you store _arrays_ of titles and dates into one row, rather than creating one row per one set of title-date (I assume that each title has a corresponding date). This way it will be much easier to manage the database. And retrieval will be also easier, as long as you add more columns to filter the select (like session id or date of browsing), you will simply iterate over the returned recordset and recreate your lists from the columns item after item